# Is it possible to get less CSS from lessphp compiler?

Tags: php, css, less, lessphp

```
require "lessc.inc.php";
$less = new lessc;
$css = $less->compileFile("style.less");
```

so I get CSS code. Is it possible to get the compiled file, but in less format?

The reason I want that is because style.less uses imports:

```
@import "color.less";
```

And I want a .less file that includes all the less code from these imports.

Comment: I'm confused. You want to combine all of your less files? Do it manually?

Comment: Can you clarify the question, please, instead of shunning my question with a multitude of dots?

Comment: I mean yes I want it to combine all files, and no I do not want to do it myself

Comment: Okay, well what is your directory structure? Can you edit your post for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is actually combining, not compiling (or converting into CSS, if you will).

I believe there's no specific LESS-targeted tool that does this, but with some customization you can use file combining tools like this - [A PowerShell Script for Combining Files](http://declanbright.xtreemhost.com/powershell-script-combine-files)